# Creating a script in google sheet that creates a table and then send in an email to the recipient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to pull certain cells from an active row. Then when I click a button or hyperlink, it creates a table. Then I need another button which sends in the table as an email to the recipient.

Can someone please suggest a simple google script which helps me achieve the same?

I tried pulling the values from the sheet and cell but I cannot insert to a specific table in a different sheet.

Comment: Welcome, please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and enrich your post with a specific question and the code you have so far. SO is not a place to just ask for a code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to send one or more records in a HTML mail as a table with header. You can use a condition or a tick box to select the row or you can use the below code

```
  var currentRow = sheet.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  var values = sheet.getRange("B"+currentRow+":AE"+currentRow).getValues();
```

to get the current row

```
//
//
function daily_mis(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var spsht = ss.getSheetByName("Spares");
  var sendto="email id";
  var message = "Report</b><br>";
  var message=message+"<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2' dir='ltr' border='1' style='font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal'"
      +"<tr>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Enq No"+"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Enq Dt"+"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Customer"+"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Material"+"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Offer Value"+"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Offer Dt"+"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+"Remarks"+"</td>"
      +"</tr>"
      +"<tr>"
  for (i=0;i<splr;i++)
     {
      if ( spvals[i][10] >= today-(24*3600*1000)) {
      //today = offer made today
      var message = message    
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+spvals[i][1]  +"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+ Utilities.formatDate(spvals[i][2],"GMT+05:30", "dd-MMM")     +"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+spvals[i][3].substring(0,15)  +"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+spvals[i][6]  +"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+spvals[i][8].toLocaleString('en-IN', { maximumFractionDigits: 0})  +"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+ Utilities.formatDate(spvals[i][10],"GMT+05:30", "dd-MMM") +"</td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#ffffff', Align = 'center'>"+spvals[i][26] +"</td>"
      +"</tr>"
      +"<tr>"
      ;
      }
  }//for row
  message=message+"</table>"+".";
  var subject='Report - '+ Utilities.formatDate(today,"GMT", "dd-MM-yy");
  GmailApp.sendEmail( sendto , subject, "", 
    {  cc: "", 
      htmlBody: message ,
    });
}//function 
//
```